# How can I compare two times, regardless of the day, in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

I want to check if DateTime.now is before or after a certain time of day. But the only time methods I can find in Ruby are measured in distance from the Epoch.

I want something like `@time = 18:00`, and then if it's currently 7AM then `DateTime.now < @time` would be `true`, no matter what day it is.

Anyone know if this can be done in Ruby?

Comment: do you want to compare just hours or hours and minutes of the current day? And you wanna plain ruby or with rails?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and the linked pages and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". Your question isn't asked well. Did you search? If not why? If so, where and why didn't it help? Did you write code? If not, why? If so, what is the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're asking about? Without examples of your code it looks like you want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's the best solution but from my point of view - the easiest. You can compare it as **Strings**

```
> time_now = Time.now.strftime('%H:%M')
#> "17:11"

> time_compare_with = '18:00'
> time_now < time_compare_with
#> true
```

Comment: @sagarpandya82 yes, it should. It's just to visualize

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _visualise_? But adding `require 'time'` implies the standard library extension is required to make your solution work and it isn't. @CarySwoveland this solution works in plain old Ruby 2.4 without the library extension.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `Time` is a `stdlib` class - should work in simple irb too. I didn't use any `ActiveSupport` features.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 agree with you